# How to echo single quotes from within shell in find exec

Tags: bash, shell, exec, single-quotes

EDIT

*Between the following answers, chepner's and Walter_A's solve the problem. Shortly, to print a single quote from within a find command, you*

*(1) use **"\047"** instead of the single quote or*

*(2) define a local variable, e.g. **q="'"** just before the find command and use **$q** instead of the single quote sign.*

*Therefore, the solution to this **specific** problem is not in using printf instead of echo or a for loop instead of find...exec, but both printf and for may help improve the code.*

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am trying to automatize the following process:

1. find certain files in current directory;
2. append a line to a text file for each file name, where the filename is preceded by the string "file " and is enclosed between single quotes.

This is in fact a simplified version of the task: the files I search for are video files and ffmpeg does some work on them before trying to write their names to a text file. The purpose of the text file is to concatenate the output files later. The full line is this:

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "name*" -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -ss 3.3 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy "out/""$0"; echo "file ""\'""$(basename -- "$0")">>mylist.txt' {} \;
```

However, the video part works well and I would just focus on the printing of the single quote (on screen or to a file), which is giving me trouble. If I try this:

```
      find . -iname "*" -exec sh -c 'echo "file ""$0"' {} \;
```

I get, as expected:

```
       file a1.mp4
       file a2.mp4
       [...]
```

I now add a single quote before the file name $0; between double or single quotes, escaped or not (if escaped, I also tried it without quotes), between quotes after a dollar sign, but all I get is the symbol ">" followed by a blinking cursor, waiting for more input.

I have tried to insert the single quote as: "\'", '\'', \', $''', $'\'', $"\'"; 
I have put it within the string "file ", with and without single or double quotes; I have set a variable v="file ""\'""$0" within the exec and echoed **it**, between double quotes. All my attempts have failed, though. It would be good to understand why. Perhaps there is something to learn here... Thank you for the advice you might give.

______________ WORKAROUND _______________

I have found a workaround. I write a bash file instead of giving a single command from the Terminal. Before the find line I export a variable SQ="'". Then my find line becomes:

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*" -exec sh -c 'echo "file ""$SQ""$(basename -- "$0")""$SQ"' {} \;
```

And it works. Perhaps the single quotes occurring in an exported variable are not treated in the same way as single quotes occurring in strings within the shell or in local variables?

Comment: It's not clear why your initial `find` command is so complicated. You can get the expected output with `find . -exec echo file {} \;`.

Comment: As I wrote, I took away a longish ffmpeg part because it doesn't impact on the problem. But the context in which the problem arises is precisely so complicated. --- Can I ask that the  negative vote is explained?

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I can't guess what the downvoted was thinking. But there is probably a simpler solution to what you want that doesn't involve `find` at all.

Comment: This is good to hear. At any rate, I have edited and added the full original line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a quote to a temp variable (I also remove the path).

```
q="'" find . -iname "*" -exec sh -c 'echo "file $q${0##*/}$q"' {} \;
```

Comment: Thx. This is surely more elegant than exporting a variable. Your answer can also be combined with chepner's and use \047 instead of $q. I also liked the pattern matching -- basename is sort of overkill in this context.

Comment: @Walter_A Sure, I have already upvoted chepner's answer and yours, but my vote doesn't appear because I have lost reputation (I must have robbed a bank or been downvoted somewhere). You and chepner provide two different answers but they are both effective. I'm a bit uncertain about the accepted answer but I'm going to edit the question and recap them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` instead of `echo`.

```
find . -iname "*" -exec printf "file '%s'" {} \;
```

To avoid forking the external `printf` for each file, use `sh` to get access to a shell builtin, use

```
find . -iname "*" -exec sh -c 'for f; do printf "file \047%s\047\n" "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

The loop in the shell and the `+` terminator ensures that `sh` will be run as few times as possible. The quoting issue is avoided by using `\047` to instruct `printf` to output a single quote.

---

Update: I would replace `find` with a simple shell loop instead.

```
for full in name*; do
    f=$(basename "$full")
    ffmpeg -i "$full" -ss 3.3 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy "out/$f"
    printf "file '%s'\n" "$f" >> mylist.txt
done
```

Comment: I am. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for both your suggestions. I'd just take away the redirection to /dev/null because I like to see the output... ;-)

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll take that out and put the redirection to `mylist.txt` back inside the loop.

Comment: Better also to add a newline, because a line for every filename is required: printf "file '%s'\n" "$f"

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this line do the same thing?

```
find . -iname "*" -exec sh -c 'echo "file" "$(basename $0)"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a single quote inside a pair of single quotes, use `'"'"'`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*" -exec sh -c 'echo "file '"'"'$(basename -- "$0")'"'"'"' {} \;
```

Explanation of `'"'"'`:

First `'` closes previous single quote

"'" inserts a single quote

Last `'` restart single-quoted-string.